# How to get Pulseaudio working with Music Player Daemon?

Tags: headless

I installed MPD, to prevent crackling sound I want to use pulseaudio.

So I configured MPD to use pulseaudio:

```
audio_output {
  type   "pulse"
  name   "MPD PulseAudio Output"
  server "localhost"
}
```

But then MPD cannot connect to pulseaudio:

```
output: Failed to open "Analoge uitgang" [pulse]: failed to connect: Connection refused
```

Pulseaudio reports nothing more than "access denied, connection closed".

To fix this problem I performed all the steps described here: http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/PulseAudio

I restarted MPD and Pulseaudio many times and also rebooted the Raspberry pi many times, but it still doesn't work.

How can I give MPD access to Pulseaudio?

I don't think I'm running the X11-bell plugin. I have a recent 512MB raspberry pi model which I run headless with `2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian`. I only installed MPD, Avahi and Samba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `server` setting from MPD and now it works. I added the server setting in the first place to fix an other error.

```
audio_output {
  type   "pulse"
  name   "MPD PulseAudio Output"
}
```

Comment: Glad you could solve your problem. Thank for sharing! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add Music Player Daemon user to the `audio` group.

1. Look for the user used by MPD:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/passwd
   # ...
   # some users
   # ...

   # the user you are looking for is probably something like this:
   mpd:x:142:142:Music Player Daemon,,,:/path/to/mpd/home:/bin/false

   # ...
   # some others users
   # ...
   ```

   What you need is the first field of the line (`mpd` in my example).
2. Add this user to the `audio` group:

   ```
   $ sudo adduser mpd audio
   ```

Comment: MPD runs under the user mpd and I already added user mpd to the audio group. Didn't fix the problem. Thanks though. The MPD wiki page states that I need to add user mpd to the group pulse-rt, but this group is not on my system. Might this be the problem?

Comment: After Googling a bit, you aren't alone with this problem. In what groups is the user `mpd`? (`$ groups mpd`)

Comment: mpd is in groups audio, pulse and pulse-access